# Process steps for migrating TFS 2010 to another environment

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Is there a migration Process guide for migrating TFS 2010 with sharepoint services to another Active Directory? what are the software installation steps and the data migration steps? What are the sets of data (types of data sources like files,DB data etc) we need to look into?

Answer (score 1):

I think, the main problem would be to change user accounts. You can use "TFSConfig.exe /identities" command to move all users and references to a new domain.
TFSconfig.exe is not part of a TFS Client installation. It is part of TFS Server installation. you can find it under Tools directory of TFS Installation folder.

Also, here is a link to MS documentation about moving TFS to a new domain.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404860.aspx
Take a look at section "Environment-based Move"